# What is a difference for authors when publishing in a journal with 300 annual papers compared to an open access journal publishing 9000 papers a year?

Tags: online-publication, open-access

Both journals are indexed by major search engines and have similar ratings. From my point of view (with limited experience), if you are researching a narrow subject and you have found online an article matching your interest, would you care from which publishing house this article came from?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? And your title mentions authors whereas the body seems to be from the perspective of someone reading an article.

Comment: @BryanKrause - this is an author concerned about potential readers.

Comment: You didn't ask this, but there is a difference in cost to the author between these two - quite substantial, usually.

Comment: @Buffy - publishing 'open source' in Elsevier will cost you twice more than in MDPI

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify both options were open source

Comment: @DavidKetcheson - you can publish your article 'open source' in most of the journals. But in MDPI journals it is the only option.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I've ever even had a wisp of thought in my head about how many articles a given journal publishes when I read a particular paper.

However, I have been concerned about whether it's worth reading a paper in certain venues that I don't trust to conduct rigorous peer review. If the paper is central to what I'm working on I have no choice but to read and evaluate for myself, but the majority of papers I look at I'm looking for something specific besides the primary hypothesis the authors are interested in: something about their methodology or a reference value for some group, and if I'm searching through dozens of papers I may not spend as much time on the ones published somewhere I don't trust.

Comment: Bryan Krause - thank you. That confirms my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to answer.  I think a reasonable framework to try to suss it out is the rigor of the review process of the two journals as an indicator of the level of trust a scientist can put in the papers they read.

Assuming all other things are equal, it takes a much bigger network on the part of section editors to find qualified reviewers for 9000 papers than for 300 papers.  My assumption is that there's some limit to the amount of work you can ask of a section editor.

So, the way you pose your question, if the staff involved in reviewing at the journal with 9000 publications was 20-30 times bigger than that of the journal with 300 publications, I would probably be able to accept that the quality of the peer review were roughly equivalent, and then move on to asking other questions about which journal I would send a manuscript to.

In reality, such considerations would probably not work into my decision making process.  I'd start by considering which journals people in my area tend to publish in, impact factor, which journals appear in my citation list ...

Note that the factors in my "real" decision tree are not independent of the question you're asking -- if the editorial standards of the journal publishing 9000 papers per year were not up to snuff, I assume that that journal would not attract the papers of people in my field that I respect, and would not have a good impact factor.

Comment: Scott Seidman - on a personal level, I feel a huge disconnect. I went through 5 journals and 3 publishing houses with my article. And I did not see even one intelligent and thoughtful sentence from neither support personal, editors or reviewers. On the other hand, when you read discussion boards like this one, you see highly intelligent discussions about the peer-review process.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance Do you have an advisor/mentor helping you?

Comment: @BryanKrause - Yes. I worked on this article with a professor who published dozens of articles and books. Reviews were actually helpful for our article. But the level of comments  and templated sentences from editors install doubts about the usefulness of the peer-review process.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145020/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-seidman-what-is-a-difference-for-authors-when-publ); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.